# How to fix the error in Login Validation Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when trying to login on my android screen. I have two fields that requires user to enter username and password, it should then go and check sqlite db if correct they will be navigated to anotherscreen(user loggedin) if incorrect they will be notified via toast message. My problem is when i hit login button my app displays "The application Database has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"! Please someone help!!My code is posted below

UserLogin.java:

```
public class UserLogin extends Activity {

public static String getName;
public static String getPassword;
EditText name,pwd;
Button login,signup;
DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ulogin);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);


    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(getBaseContext());
            dataBaseHandler.open();
            String getName = name.getText().toString();
            String getPassword = pwd.getText().toString();

            System.out.println("print something");

            if(getName.equals("")||getName==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User Name Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("User name empty");
            }
            else if(getPassword.equals("")||getPassword==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Password empty");
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {

                    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT txtUserName,txtPassword FROM mytable WHERE txtUserName= ? AND txtPassword= ?", new String[] {getName, getPassword});
                    if(c.moveToFirst())
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User Name and Password is Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(UserLogin.this, LoggedIn.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        System.out.println("User name and Password correct correct");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User Name and Password is not Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("User name and password is not correct");
                    }
                }
                catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            dataBaseHandler.close();

        }

    });
```

DataBaseHandler.java:

public class DataBaseHandler {

```
public static final String NAME = "txtUserName";
public static final String PASSWORD = "txtPassword";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table mytable(txtUserName text primary key not null, txtPassword password not null, email text not null);";

private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
Context ctx;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public DataBaseHandler(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
}
private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DataBaseHelper(Context ctx){
        super(ctx,DATA_BASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable");
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
public DataBaseHandler open(){
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    dbHelper.close();
}

public long insertData(String txtUserName, String txtPassword, String email){
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(NAME,txtUserName);
    content.put(PASSWORD,txtPassword);
    content.put(EMAIL,email);
    return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}

public String getAllData()
{
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {NAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cursor.getString(0);
        String pwd = cursor.getString(1);
        String email = cursor.getString(2);
        buffer.append(name+" "+pwd+" "+email+""+"\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}



public Cursor returnData(){
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {NAME,PASSWORD,EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.example.databasesplash.UserLogin$1.onClick(UserLogin.java:67)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-05 10:40:43.165: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ur getting SQL Exception.....where is UserLogin.java:67??????????

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look in your code you use the `db variable` like this

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT txtUserName,txtPassword FROM mytable WHERE txtUserName= ? AND txtPassword= ?", new String[] {getName, getPassword});
```

but you declare it like

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
```

so the db current value is `null` which causes the NPE in your application

in your `dbhelper class`  you have

```
public DataBaseHandler open(){
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

i think it should be

```
public SQLiteDatabase open(){
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }
```

but in your `UserLogin Activity` in `onClick method` you call the open like this

```
dataBaseHandler.open();
```

instead of

```
db=dataBaseHandler.open();
```